Stack Overflow Jobs - FAQ help page - help article link is linked with "/link"
On the "Stack Overflow Jobs -> Frequently Asked Questions" help page, the 5th point discusses how to report a job.
However, the provided link redirects to a 404 error page. Upon inspecting the element, the link is erroneously set to "/link".
The actual content from the help page:

5. How do I report a job?
Information on how to report a problem with a job listing can be found in this help article.

Screenshot for reference:


To close voters: note that the help article is also available on some Technology SE site. (Also found a bug that the help article can be searched on non-Technology site, but doesn't exist when accessed...)

To be fair, the [stack-overflow-jobs] tag excerpt is wildly unclear about whether posts should be made here or MSE.

This link should now be fixed.
